# SQL Complex select statement?

Tags: mysql, date

I have on table, that I record Car#,Date,RunHours as bellow:

```
Car#        Date         RunHours
125      2014-01-01       1250
125      2014-02-10       3250
215      2014-02-11       1400
215      2014-03-01       1800
125      2014-03-15       4100
215      2014-04-10       2500
```

I need the select result as bellow:

```
Car#        Date        Runhours   Previous_Date     Previous_RunHours
125      2014-01-01       1250           N/A               N/A
125      2014-02-10       3250       2014-01-01           1250
215      2014-02-11       1400           N/A               N/A
215      2014-03-01       1800       2014-02-11           1400
125      2014-03-15       4100       2014-02-10           3250
215      2014-04-10       2500       2014-02-11           1800
```

How can I do it.

Comment: The Previous_Date in the last row should be 2014-03-01, right?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one method, using correlated subqueries to get the previous information:

```
select t.*,
       (select t2.date
        from table t2
        where t2.car = t.car and t2.date < t.date
        order by t2.date desc
        limit 1
       ) as prev_date,
       (select t2.runhours
        from table t2
        where t2.car = t.car and t2.date < t.date
        order by t2.date desc
        limit 1
       ) as prev_runhours
from table t;
```

For performance, you want an index on `table(car, date)`.

Comment: Checking and I'll feed back